# How to maintain a object list to remember these objects 's state change?

Tags: c#, object

i need to remember something (exactly is  route) 's state change , my approach is  : at first create a list (call it LOR) of object base on something 's state , after this ,  every 10 mins requery these routes 's state again , and reset LOR 's property , when any a route in LOR 's property is changed , this route will raise an event .

here is the code :

at first , i create a list of object Route

```
List<Route> listOfRouteObj = new List<Route>();
```

the define of my object is :

```
class Route
{

    public class EventArgsPriority : EventArgs
    {
        public int oldPriority { get; set; }
        public int newPriority { get; set; }
    }
    public delegate void PriorityChangedEventHandler(EventArgsPriority e);

    public event PriorityChangedEventHandler onPriorityChanged;


    #region properties

    private int miPriority = 3000;
    public int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return miPriority;
        }
        internal set
        {
            if (miPriority != value)
            {
                PriorityChangedEventHandler handler = onPriorityChanged;
                EventArgsPriority aps = new EventArgsPriority();
                aps.oldPriority = miPriority;
                aps.newPriority = value;
                handler(aps);
            }
            miPriority = value;
        }
    }

    //

    private string mstrRouteID = "";
    public string RouteID
    {
        get
        {
            return mstrRouteID;
        }
        internal set
        {
            mstrRouteID = value;
        }
    }


    //
    public Route(int iPriority, string strRoutrID)
    {
        miPriority = iPriority;

        mstrRouteID = strRoutrID;

    }

}
```

and at the first query , i got some route's state and in a loop , i create all route object and add them to list :

```
  Route r1 = new Route(int.Parse(row["priority"].ToString()),row["routeID"].ToString());

  r1.onPriorityChanged += new Route.PriorityChangedEventHandler(onRoutePriorityChanged);

  listOfRouteObj .add(r1);
```

where onRoutePriorityChanged  function is :

```
private void onRoutePriorityChanged(Route.EventArgsPriority e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.oldPriority.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(e.newPriority.ToString());
}
```

until now , every thing is ok ,

but what i do not know is : when time come to next  query after 10 mins ,among these Routes , some is down, some is new added , some 's priority is changed , How can i update my  listOfRouteObj  to the newest state ?  for example , to the route which ID =1 , update it 's priority from 1000 to 2000 base on new situation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var route = listOfRouteObj.SingleOrDefault(route => route.RouteID.Equals("1"));
if(route != null)
   route.Priority = 1000;
```

Is this what you mean??

Comment: maybe yes , let me test it

Comment: @yangl Ok, let me know if it passed your test ;-)